# how to achieve key value pair based validation in MS excel?

Tags: excel, validation

I know how to make a cell value picked from a list of values using data -> validation -> list ...

I have to extend this to similar functionality that there will be 2 similar lists. lets say {simple, average, complex} & {3, 5, 7}

in the cell (lets say D3) when I select simple the value in E3 should change to 3 and vice versa... how to achieve this in excel ?

Comment: Check for `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH` functions

Comment: To make the changes **bi-directional**, you could use a macro.

Comment: ... specifically something like a Worksheet_Change event procedure.

Comment: The volunteers here are not here to play Twenty Questions with you. If you do some research and come back after you have written some code and  you have a [specific programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) be sure to provide enough information that someone who isn't sitting in front of your computer screen can understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example.  Say we put the data validation *(DV)* lookup list in cells **D5** through **E7**.  Then manually put *DV* in **D3** and **E3**:

[image]

Then install the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim E As Range, D As Range
    Dim i As Long, v As Variant

    Set E = Range("E3")
    Set D = Range("D3")
    If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    v = Target.Value
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Not Intersect(Target, E) Is Nothing Then
            i = .Match(v, Range("E5:E7"), 0)
            D.Value = Range("D5").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
        End If
        If Not Intersect(Target, D) Is Nothing Then
            i = .Match(v, Range("D5:D7"), 0)
            E.Value = Range("E5").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```